# The TestCase attribute using NUnit 3.12 is missing...?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nunit

I see "[TestCase]" documented for NUnit at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCase-Attribute, but IntelliSense doesn't detect it.

I downloaded the NUnit source, and can see it exists.  "[Test]" works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "Intellisense doesn't detect it?"

Comment: In any file that is part of an assembly referencing the NUnit framework, with a `using NUnit.Framework` statement, you should be able to start typing "[T" and see `Test`, `TestCase`, `TestCaseSource`, etc.

Comment: Could you check if you test project correctly reference `nunit`?

Comment: OK, found it.  I had only updated a single project to NUnit 3.12, leaving a different project on an older NUnit version 2.4.*, which doesn't support [TestCase].

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution, then updated all projects in the solution to NUnit 3.11, which I downloaded from https://github.com/nunit/nunit/releases/tag/v3.11.